# Осталось лишь несколько человек. Или остались?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, сказуемые, единственное-множественное-число, счетный-оборот

*Остал**о**сь лишь несколько человек, которые...* Или *остал**и**сь*?
На что необходимо ориентироваться при выборе "осталось" или "остались" — на "несколько" или "которые"?

Comment: Решить задачу БЕЗ КОНТЕКСТА не представляется возможным. Приведенная форма в равной степени  подходит как для множественного, так и для единственного числа.

Comment: "Вскоре почти все жители острова уехали. Осталось лишь несколько человек, которые не захотели бросать свою землю".

Comment: Тут оба варианта подходят. Остались лишь несколько человек. = Лишь несколько человек взяли и не уехали.(Целенаправленное действие, которое совершила группа людей.) Осталось несколько человек. = Положение на острове  было такое, что там было только несколько человек, а остальные уехали.(Характеристика совокупности в отношении количества.) Вы вправе конструировать оба этих смысла, которые не сильно различаются.

Comment: «Вскоре почти все жители острова уехали. Остались лишь несколько человек, которые не захотели бросать свою землю». Здесь я выбрала бы множественное число: значение АКТИВНОГО действия. Они же НЕ ГОЛОСОВАЛИ, останемся или нет, каждый принимал решения за себя. "Тут оба варианта подходят"? Походят, да НЕ ОДИНАКОВО подходят. Двух одинаково верных вариантов вообще не существует в природе, в каждой конкретной ситуации один из них чем-то лучше другого. Иначе проблема выбора ведет ко всем известному результату, о чем сказано в притче "Буриданов осел".  Стоит задуматься... :))

Comment: Кстати, здесь  же в СПП  три сказуемых  уехали, остались, не захотели –  поэтому желательно использовать ОДИНАКОВУЮ форму, но тогда и выбирать-то НЕЧЕГО.  Раньше на эту тему приводился другой пример: Осталось лишь несколько человек, которые к тому же небоеспособны.  Но это же совсем другое дело, сказуемое в придаточном предложении – это всего лишь оценка качества, тогда возможно сочетание ед. числа (осталось)  в главном и мн. числа в придаточном (небоеспособны). Но в приведенном полном предложении  корректно смотрится  только мн. число (остались).

Answer (score 4):

«Остались», — говорят при целенаправленном действии, которое производится неким субъектом.
Учительница просила остаться и помочь с уборкой класса, а остались лишь несколько человек. (Тут нельзя сказать: «осталось».)
После угроз со стороны правительства, на митинге остались только несколько человек. (Тут нельзя сказать: «осталось». Конечно, можно, но будет другой смысл.)

«Осталось», — говорят, когда характеризуют совокупность в отношении текущего количества.
Осталось немного денег. (Тут нельзя сказать: «остались».)
Осталось немного порядочных людей. (Тут нельзя сказать: «остались».)
Я не могу идти дальше: у меня не осталось сил. (Тут нельзя сказать: «остались».)
Мои одноклассники уже почти все мертвы. Осталось лишь несколько человек. (Тут нельзя сказать: «остались».)

Но есть исключения, вроде: «В голодающее племя было доставлено продовольствие, но несколько жителей всё равно остались голодными».

Comment: _Jim Korbett_, мне кажется, что Вы смешали все в одну кучу. Зачем нам примеры со словом "немного"? Ведь это наречие (тут совсем другие правила согласования). А в вопросе присутствует "несколько" — числительное. Конечно, никто и не скажет по-другому: **осталось** немного (мало, чуть-чуть, немножко, маленько, чуток...) денег.

Comment: Я привел универсальную инструкцию для всех случаев, не считая каких-то тонкостей, которые мне лень описывать. Ни на «несколько», ни на «которые» не следует ориентироваться, потому что от них ничего не зависит, а зависит от контекста, и то, как зависит от контекста, я описал.  Предложение: «Осталось лишь несколько человек, которые...» — может быть как с «осталось», так и с «остались». Точнее, не от контекста, а от того, что вы хотите сказать этим предложением.

Answer (score 4):

Вот что разъясняет Розенталь:

> **11.** При наличии в количественно-именном сочетании слова ***несколько*** возможна постановка сказуемого как в форме единственного, так и в форме множественного числа. Например:
> а) *За оградой **стояло несколько саней**...* (Пушкин); ***Несколько человек оглянулось...*** (Горький); ***Несколько** рыбачьих **баркасов заблудилось** в море* (Куприн);
> б) ***Несколько дам** скорыми шагами **ходили** взад и вперед по площадке...* (Лермонтов); *Что **могли сделать несколько** молодых **студентов**!* (Герцен); ***Заговорили** сначала **несколько человек** туманно и нетвердо...* (Фадеев).
> Ср. различное согласование однородных сказуемых в одном и том же предложении в зависимости от того, обозначают они активное действие или пассивное состояние, совместное или раздельное действие: *За дверью **находилось несколько человек** и как будто кого-то **отталкивали*** (Достоевский); *Замок бани сломали, **несколько человек втиснулось** в двери и почти тотчас же **вылезли** оттуда* (Горький).

Местоимение [**который**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/90842), связанное с сочетанием *несколько человек*, всегда будет стоять во множественном числе — *которые* (и уже не важно, какую форму вы выберете; несколько кого-то или чего-то — это ведь не один).
Осталось лишь несколько человек, которые...
Остались лишь несколько человек, которые...

Отмечу, что при наличии частицы [**лишь**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%8C) (она подчёркивает исключительность, единственность кого-либо, чего-либо, какого-либо явления, процесса и т.п.; только, исключительно, единственно) предпочтительна все-таки форма единственного числа (осталось).
Об этом, кстати, говорит и статистика Нацкорпуса:
[осталось лишь несколько](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&g=i_doc&dpp=10&spp=50&text=lexform&req=%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE&kwsz=5&mode=main&sr=1&spd=10&nodia=1&out=normal) — 32;
[остались лишь несколько](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE) — 3.

[Сказуемое при подлежащем — количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте)](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/70091268.html)

Comment: Спасибо, что бы выбрали Вы?..

Comment: Маруся, я уже отметила: единственное число (хотя, конечно же, контекст бы не помешал). _Наше поколение уже почти всё вымерло, осталось лишь несколько человек_ (Л. Ахеджакова о смерти Мягкова). _Постепенно Михаил Афанасьевич устал от больших компаний, и среди его постоянных гостей осталось лишь несколько человек_ (коллектив авторов, из статьи).

Comment: Почему единственное? Вот два примера: 1. Нашу дивизию  смяли! Осталось лишь несколько человек, которые к тому же небоеспособны. 2. Учительница просила всех остаться и помочь ей с уборкой. Остались лишь несколько человек, которые, несмотря на малочисленность, быстро со всем управились.

Comment: Статистика нац. корпуса не говорит о предпочтительности использования «осталось», а говорит о том, что смысл предложения с «осталось» конструируют намного чаще. Как раз таки наличие примеров с «остались» говорит о том, что все зависит от того, какой смысл вы конструируете.